# Is there a way to change ActionListeners from public void to something else?

Tags: java, swing, methods, return-type

I'm trying to run a public static int when a JButton is pressed, but I cant run it from the public void. Is there any way I can get around that?

```
btnGoMining.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Mining(randomOre, oresGet, mineTime, Inventory);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the `public static int`?

Comment: You can call static methods from non-static. If you want a return value for `actionPerformed()`, that's not possible (where would it be returned anyway?). You can assign return values from `static int` methods normally in the `actionPerformed()` body.

Comment: you can't "run a public static int". Please explain what you want to achieve, preferrably with a code sample. "running an int" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: If I understand correctly (& I am fairly confident I don't), you want the action performed to return an object or a primitive (e.g. `int`).  That is not practical.  It will be necessary to look at other areas of the design in order to fix this.  One possible way is to call a method from within the action performed that accepts an integer or object value.  What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve here?  Explain it to me like I was a user and this was a feature.  E.G. *"Click the 'Create Miner' button to start your adventure!"*

Answer (score 1):

No. The interface defines the method signature, so the only thing you can do is add `final` or `synchronized` to it since they're not considered to be part of the method signature.